# Configuration of SSL in DB2 LUW

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I am configuring SSL in db2 AIX server. Getting the following error in diaglog:

> "gsk_secure_soc_init" failed with error code "410"  in
>   "sqlccSSLSocketSetup"

**DB2 version:9.7 FP10**

All SSL parameters are set and have generated self signed certificate.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: When do you get that error?

Comment: I did SSL configuration in server and when I try to catalog this in client and connect. Getting this error.

Comment: This does not belong on SO, it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This issue belongs to DB2 database. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following article. Sounds like you may need to look into your GSKit configuration: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21693912

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you mean to say it's the problem from application side. Like missing configurations?Because on server side configuration looks perfect for me.

Comment: Yes. It might be best to paste the entire db2diag.log entry. There you will see the process name, application ID, and thread ID. Those three elements can be used to map to the executing application.

Comment: 2015-08-17-10.50.03.202094-300 I970720A475        LEVEL: Error
PID     : 15139006             TID  : 17639       PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2instd             NODE : 000         DB   : ERDDEV
APPHDL  : 0-16461
EDUID   : 17639                EDUNAME: db2agent () 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, common communication, sqlccMapSSLErrorToDB2Error, probe:30
MESSAGE : DIA3604E The SSL function "gsk_secure_soc_init" failed with the
          return code "410" in "sqlccSSLSocketSetup".

Comment: 2015-08-17-10.50.03.202417-300 I971196A726        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 15139006             TID  : 17639       PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2instd             NODE : 000         DB   : ERDDEV
APPHDL  : 0-16461
EDUID   : 17639                EDUNAME: db2agent () 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, DRDA Application Server, sqljsInitAgent, probe:10
DATA #1 : String, 15 bytes
sqlccinit rc =
DATA #2 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes
54
DATA #3 : Communication Failure Condition, PD_TYPE_COMCONDITION, 284 bytes

Comment: Communication Condition
                SEVERITY      = 0
                NUMBER TOKENS = 7
                MSG TOKEN[0]  = 410
                MSG TOKEN[1]  = *
                MSG TOKEN[2]  = *
                MSG TOKEN[3]  = SSL
                MSG TOKEN[4]  = SOCKETS
                MSG TOKEN[5]  =
                MSG TOKEN[6]  = sqlccSSLSocketSetup

Comment: 2015-08-17-10.50.03.202588-300 I971923A470        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 15139006             TID  : 17639       PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2instd             NODE : 000         DB   : ERDDEV
APPHDL  : 0-16461
EDUID   : 17639                EDUNAME: db2agent () 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, DRDA Application Server, sqljsDrdaAsInnerDriver, probe:10
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x824B0001=-2109014015=SQLJS_ICE "Internal Error"
          DIA8532C An internal processing error has occurred.

Comment: 2015-08-17-10.50.14.693729-300 I974453A425        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 15139006             TID  : 2057        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2instd             NODE : 000
EDUID   : 2057                 EDUNAME: db2tcpcm 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, common communication, sqlcctcpconnmgr_child, probe:103
MESSAGE : DIA3421W "TCPIP" protocol support: Environment Variable value
          "DB2SOSNDBUF" = "65536" is "accepted".

Comment: 2015-08-17-10.50.14.694086-300 I975305A393        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 15139006             TID  : 2057        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2instd             NODE : 000
EDUID   : 2057                 EDUNAME: db2tcpcm 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, common communication, sqlcctcpconnmgr_child, probe:117
MESSAGE : DIA3219I Client connecting from IP address = "10.240.1.36", port =
          "42524".

Comment: Above are the logs. Yeah as you said it will be easy analyse more on diag logs. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: OK, so the problem is coming from APPHDL : 0-16461 EDUID : 17639 EDUNAME: db2agent. A simple `LIST APPLICATIONS SHOW DETAIL` or `GET SNAPSHOT FOR APPLICATIONS` will tell you where the app came from. HTH.

Comment: Hi Pavel, sorry for the delay will post list application show detail results here:

Comment: CONNECT Auth Id    Application Name     Appl.      Application Id   Seq#  Number of  Coordinating DB  Coordinator     Status     Status Change Time         DB Name  DB Path       Handle   Agents     partition number pid/thread
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WTXDEV1       db2fw7               7763       *LOCAL.DB2.150818124914                                        00001 1          0                13992           Connect Completed              Not Collected              ERDDEV   /db/db2instd/db2data/erddev/db2instd/NODE0000/SQL00001/

Comment: I have added just one application show details: as I can't paste here everything. We can't even attach the file here I guess.